# SharePoint 2016 - Multiline text field lost data on workflow init

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, document-library, 2016

I have a strange problem with multiline text field on Document Library on SharePoint 2016 site. I have a workflow attached to a Document Library with manual start (not automatically with upload or modify). This workflow create a basic approval task and modify a status field.

In some cases, not always, multiline field lost data on workflow init.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you got this behavior when the `Multi-Line field` holds **more than 255 characters** and in this case, its content truncated to 255 characters or lost!!

> **Note:** The maximum allowable length for strings in workflow text fields is 255 characters.

Answer (score 0):

When using Multiple lines field in a library, there is one option "Allow unlimited length in document libraries" like below:

[image]

Please check this point in your side and make sure enabled this option to Yes if there is too long characters in this field.